# How to setup a LAN network in Wireless?

Tags: wireless-networking, linux-distributions, wifi-configuration, wifi-transfer

I know the way to give a IP and make a network in wired system. But having no idea, How to make a network in Wireless system.

I would like to do a home network with 4 laptop. One laptop is wifi enabled and we could use it as a Access Point. How to add other laptop into a same group by providing IP.

Comment: refer [this](http://mypublicwifi.com/publicwifi/en/index.html)

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath : Thanks for the lovely tool. Will it work on Linux machine (I think itz not). Can you suggest me for linux environment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ubuntu, then you are able to configure hotspot with the option `use as Hotspot` in [wireless network settings](http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/). Otherwise you can achieve the same by using [hostapd](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But Still having one doubt in my mind. How to specify a Ip address between computers in wireless (For making a restriction based on IP address).

Comment: you will get a nice "howto" from [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-a-wi-fi-hotspot-access-point-mode)

Answer (score 0):

I hope [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/setting-wireless-network#1TC=windows-7) is what you are searching for...Please inform me if I am correct so that I can edit the answer with the relevant details..

Comment: Really sorry for putting up a question in confusing way. I am having linux environment. Thank you so much for the simple documentation.